# How to change sync destination

Tags: linux, perforce

### Question:

How do I change where `p4 sync` copies files to?

### Background:

I have a specific directory where I typically run:

`p4 sync //path/to/project/...`

Today, I accidentally ran the command in a different directory.

No big deal, I thought. I ran `p4 sync //...#none` and then reran `p4 sync //path/to/project/...` in the correct location.

Sadly, it still copied all files to the original, incorrect location. I tried `rm -rf` and all sorts of combinations (eg. `p4 sync -f ..`). I tried `p4 flush` but was told I had too many files...  so that probably was me almost nuking the repo. (//path/to/project/... only has about 40 files, not 50,000.)

---

I don't know much about p4 and honestly don't care, I just need it to work. [I looked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071790/p4-sync-to-an-alternate-location), but there's far more explaining and no actual help. I've never had to putz around with the client or the workspace before this point

I wrote a script when I first started 1.5 years ago than auto-gens this bs for each new //path/to/**project**/... , so nothing different than the project I successfully tackled 2 weeks ago, or 2 weeks before that, etc..

The only difference is the directory I ran the first `p4 sync` command in. In a sane world, re-running that command after `p4 sync //..#none` in a new location should pull down my files into the new location.

---

Also, bonus points: How do I convince my company that perforce is complete garbage and is probably *worse* than having no version control at all, so we can use git like every other sane company?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, I went into my client, and saw the "Root:" parameter set to the wrong directory.

I changed that to the correct directory, and ran `p4 sync`; The files appeared in the correct location.

I'm not sure how that happened, and maybe another poster can come along and explain this. (Perhaps it is generated during the first use of sync?)

Comment: "I wrote a script when I first started 1.5 years ago than auto-gens this bs" -- the Root is defined when you create the client spec (I assume that's the bs you're referring to), so the problem is probably in your script that creates the client spec.  :)  It defaults to the current directory (where you ran "p4 client" the first time prior to running "p4 sync") if you don't specify something else.

Comment: I just realized that you wrote a script that makes you a new client spec whenever you run "p4 sync".  Except it doesn't actually check to see if it's making a new client spec.  Surprised it took you 1.5 years to run into problems with that, it's... not... optimal.  :|